# Facebook Graph API Status update PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl, status

Ive managed to started working with the Facebook Graph API

Ive been able to use javascript to redirect to the permissions allow page where Ive specified "publish_stream", Ive received a valid access_token

I want to update the user's status. Following Facebook's documentation I am attempting to post to:

https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed/access_token=x&message=y

(where {user_id} is the user's facebook uid etc)

Ive tried using CURL, as well as file_get_contents so both as POST and GET requests. The only response I received is a list of the user's previous statuses, it will not update the status with the data im sending.

I must be missing something. The documentation says that's all I need

Comment: Ive tried adding variables "from" and "updated_status" as json encoded objects, still no luck

Comment: I note when I receive all the statuses back, at the very bottom of this structure is a section "paging:" which contains my last two requests, however, status remains un-updated

Comment: looks like the paging is just urls to show next or previous 25 status but appends by GET variables to it

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if you're still having problems with this code as I have a completed version which this computer doesn't have saved on it! Anyhow! One main thing I've notices is the extra '/' in your url:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed/access_token=x&message=y`

should be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/feed?access_token=x&message=y
```

and the code that I built from was

> curl -F 'access_token=...' \
>
> -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
>
> ```
> https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
> ```

and I got this code from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/#editing).

I hope this helps,

Jon